# Integrating Emberjs with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I am very new to ember js and also node js and web development in general. I have chosed to do a project using emberjs as my MVC framework and Nodejs for server side but I can't seem to find a resource that's not overwhelming for someone with my experience to integrate them. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Are you looking for tutorial suggestions? This one is great for getting started with ember and ember-data.. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember lives on the client and does not need to care what runs on the server. All you need to do on the server side is to include the [required dependencies](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/obtaining-emberjs-and-dependencies/) in your HTML template.